# Oddball Cat and Exhaust Manifold 04 Nissan Xterra

Tags: nissan, exhaust, xterra

I recently got the p0420 code and narrowed the issue down to needing a new cat. Thought i'd be smart and went to Walker identify the exhaust for a basic '04 Nissan Xterra XE, 4WD, 3.3L. Found the parts for the manifold cat, boom, purchased from Amazon. Thought I was on the road to repairing this, part comes in, take it out to the garage to drop off the cat and low and behold they don't match!

I purchased this puppy:  [Walker 16500](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C564QWA). 
But when I went to match it up. It looks like the manifold cat and the manifold are a single unit. They certainly don't have the triangular flange as indicated.   See picture: [image]

I then decided to search for the exhaust manifold, assuming that the vehiclle/model had a singular exhaust manifold/cat and only found an exhaust manifold that appears to match the cat manifold that I purchased (and was incompatible with the installed exhaust manifold). What have I missed?

Comment: Are you sure what you purchased *won't* fit your application? You may need to purchase the exhaust manifold and change out the whole thing.

Comment: That style manifold converter combo is used on the xterra vg33e engine the convertor you bought is intended for the xterra vg33er engine. Take a look at http://www.amazon.com/AP-Exhaust-641243-Catalytic-Converter/dp/compatibility-chart/B004A5L1XG I couldn't find a OE Part number.